# How can I make my background image move for a certain duration and then start moving back, and then start again?

Tags: html, css

Currently I have my background image moving to the left using the code in this post. But the issue is that my background image isn't infinite and there's an ugly jump back to the beginning once it runs out. Is there a way to prevent that or to maybe make it loop back?
Here is my html and css:

```
<div class="cantstyle">
<div id="0" class="slidebg bg" style="min-height:100em;background-image:url('footer_lodyas.png');">
<div class="hvr-underline-from-center" style="text-align:center; color:white;">
<h3 style="font-size:6em;color:white;text-align:center;margin-top:15%;"> title <span class="hvr-grow">t</span><span class="hvr-grow">t</span><span class="hvr-grow">l</span><span class="hvr-grow">E</span> </h3>
<p style="font-size:1.2em;"> subtitle </p>
<p><a href="#1">Home</a>  |  <a href="#2">Tab2</a>  |  <a href="#3">Tab3</a>  |  <a href="#4">Tab4</a></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
 .bg:hover {
        background-image: url("footer_lodyas.png");
       -webkit-animation: 3s slideBg infinite linear;
        -moz-animation: 3s slideBg infinite linear;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes slideBg {
        0% {
            background-position: 0 0;
        }
        100% {
            background-position: 200px 0;
        }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes slideBg {
        0% {
            background-position: 0 0;
        }
        100% {
            background-position: 200px 0;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Might you provide a Fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should make another section of code dedicated to moving the background image back. You should probably just repeat your current code again but instead of moving it forwards, you should move it back.

Try this:

```css
@-moz-keyframes slideBg {
    0% {
        background-position: 200px 0px;
    }

    100% {
        background-position: 0px 0px;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes slideBg {
    0% {
        background-position: 200px 0px;
    }

    100% {
        background-position: 0px 0px;
    }
}
```

Comment: This still results in a sudden jump at the end. I added this separately as you said, but still the sudden jump.

Comment: can you please supply me all of your html code please?

Comment: I added it to the main post